# Folium Filtering Markers Based on Numeric Slider

Tags: python, folium

I want to filter Markers in Folium based on sliders that can show and hide markers that fit those conditions.

For instance, I have a dataframe of housing data with, and I'm able to create a Marker Cluster for all my data based on the location:
`markerCluster = MarkerCluster(name="All houses").add_to(map)`

But I only have very basic filter control like hide/show each `Marker Cluster`. In my dataframe I want to have a slider to show/hide markers based on house value and year built, both are values in my dataframe. For instance, showing only houses between `100-200K` and built between `1980 and 1999`.

How do I do this?